# Django: How to return a Single Object (not Array) in a ModelViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get a single object out of my Profile model. That works perfectly if I use the filter method like below. However, it returns me an array that contains a single object. What I want is just the object but not inside a list/array. When I use the `get_object` function I get the error that I can not use it within the ModelViewSet.

So I wonder how can I get a single object out of my model while using a ModelViewSet?

```
class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated, 
  ]
  serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

  queryset = Profile.objects.all()

  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return self.queryset
```

Comment: `get_queryset` is supposed to return a queryset not a single object in order to work correctly.

Comment: @VishalSingh exactly. i wonder if its possible to override the 'get_queryset' to get a single object?

Comment: it is possible to override and return a single object instead of a queryset but that will break the working of the whole ViewSet.

Comment: All right! Thank you.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? You could always use e.g. `[:1]` in `get_queryset()` to limit the queryset to exactly one item, but I'm curious why.

Comment: @AKX Thank you. I pass the queryset with a single object (the profile) to my react frontend. There it appears a bit cumbersome to access the object in the array. So I thought, why not send an single object directly and get rid of the wrapping array. But that approach seems not worthy.

Comment: Right. Getting a single object is what a `retrieve` function in a viewset would do, usually implemented by DRF's RetrieveMixin